# CKFinder 2.5 doesn't recognise Coldfusion session variables

Tags: session, coldfusion, ckfinder

I'm upgrading from CKFinder 2.4 to 2.5, and have set up the Application.cfc in the ckfinder and ckfinder/core/connector/cfm folders so that the application name is the same as the as that set up for the website. I've also updated the config.cfm file to set config.baseURL = session.baseURL;

However, when I open CKEditor and attempt to use CKFinder to browse the webserver for images, I get the following error:

Element BASEURL is undefined in SESSION

The session.baseURL is defined on that page, but CKFinder appears not to have access to it.

If I swap back to using CKEditor 2.4 everything works. I must have missed out something in the 2.5 configuration, but I can't see what else to do.

Comment: What does your code look like? This isn't a ckfinder issue as that runs client side and ColdFusion is processed server side.

Comment: In order to run locally, the ckfinder app is served to the browser by ColdFusion. The relevant Application.cfm files are run first, which establish the name of the website application - which is then used to allow sharing of session variables which are referenced in the config.cfm file when that is loading. This is all covered in the ckfinder documentation. It works nicely for v.2.4. The exact same setup isn't working for v.2.5.

Comment: You're going to need to produce some code if you want any kind of an answer.   The error you're giving us isn't an error ckfinder itself can generate. Something is going wrong server side.

Comment: These are the scope variables for my website:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've sorted the problem - the application name for my application is netlist, and I'd entered it as Netlist in the two Application.cfc files. I forgot that JavaScript is case sensitive.